# Magento change space between main navigation links

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

This should be easy, but I'm not getting any useful results.

www.wilfrednewman.com

I'm trying to edit the menu and keep it on one line. Either forced one line or edit the spacing on my own.

I changed a bunch of margin/padding settings for the ul(got the ul name from top.phtml, then changed skin/frontend/default/blanco/css/menu1.css, but it isn't changing anything.

Using blanco theme. Any ideas to get me started?

Thanks!

Edit: Had to change the name to 'STORE' so it would show up on the same line for the time being. But if I change it to Online Store, instead of pushing the menu items closer together it defaults to two lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need `#nav > li{padding:8px 15px;}` in `menu1.css`. Change the 15px value up or down to tune the spacing.

If it isn't making any difference check that the CSS file is not cached anywhere (from Magento back-end right through to your browser).

Comment: Perfect! I had to add this in, it wasn't there before